# Azure deploy error errno 47

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I'm trying to deploy a nodeJS application in azure. In deployment i have the npm ERR! errno 47.

Maybe can help that i had exceded the maximum character paths while developing, which i fixed it locally.

All answers would be appreciate.

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling node.js deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'index.js'
Copying file: 'mmfrontend-crm-node.njsproj'
Copying file: 'package.json'
Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.17, 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.12.0.
Selected node.js version 0.10.32. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
npm WARN package.json mmfrontend-crm-node@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json mmfrontend-crm-node@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN deprecated gulp-clean@0.3.1: use gulp-rimraf instead
npm WARN engine imagemin@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0","npm":">=2.1.5"} (current: {"node":"0.10.32","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-pngquant@4.0.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-optipng@4.2.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-jpegtran@4.1.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-gifsicle@4.1.0
npm ERR! EEXIST, open 'D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\5428a087-m-cache-wrappy-1-0-1-package-tgz.lock'
File exists: D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\5428a087-m-cache-wrappy-1-0-1-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again. 
 npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.10.32\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.4.28\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\5428a087-m-cache-wrappy-1-0-1-package-tgz.lock
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
Failed exitCode=47, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.32\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.28\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

Comment: could be this [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6309). Try updating npm ( for [windows](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows)) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Redeploy worked, a bit strange with azure